# Dock a resizable wpf DataGrid at bottom of window

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

In a WPF project, I want to dock a DataGrid to the bottom of a window so that if the window resizes, I will be able to utilize more of the DataGrid. Like this:

[image]

How do I do that? All my DockPanel attempts have failed.

The current attempt is here:

```
<Window x:Class="Foo.SQLDialog"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Foo.Controls"
   Title="test" ResizeMode="CanResize" Width="400" Height="400">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Content="SQL" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
      <TextBox Width="377" Height="100" Name="txtSQL"/>
      <Button Content="Run SQL" Click="Button_Click_1" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Result" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <ScrollViewer Width="Auto" Height="180" DockPanel.Dock="Right,Bottom"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <DataGrid x:Name="dataResult" />
    </ScrollViewer>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The height of the scrollviewer+datagrid will not adapt however.

Comment: I have tried a lot. Will not list everything here. If I put a DockPanel around the DataGrid and set the dockpanels height, the height will remain when the window is resized.

Comment: I added some code now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, using `DockPanel.Dock` without having a DockPanel as a parent doesn't do much...

In my example I changed your root `StackPanel` to a `DockPanel` so it will work as you want.
I also used **[DockPanel.LastChildFill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill.aspx)** property which makes sure the last child of the DockPanel will get all the remaining space:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Label Content="SQL" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBox Width="377" Height="100" Name="txtSQL"/>
        <Button Content="Run SQL" Click="Button_Click_1" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom,Right"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataResult"  />
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Finally, to make it really stretch on all the remaining space, I removed the `Height` property you set, as this blocked it from stretching.

Comment: Thanks! I put DockPanel.Dock="Top" and HorizontalAlignment="Left" on the label as well!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if useful or if i understand you question the right way but have you tried this:

```
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Right, Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ></DataGrid>
```